# C#, cmd line application creates object on first call, uses object in all subsequent calls

Tags: c#, command, cmd

I would like to create a command line application in C# where users could use it as a script language.  By this I mean upon the first run of the application, an instance of an object is created, and persists throughout the rest of the session.  Any subsequent calls of the application from the command line use parameters set previously.

For instance if you had an application called woo.exe, which created an object called ball.  Ball has a method called changeColor which accepts a string as input. Our command line call for changeColor would be.

> > woo changeColor red

Now if ball had a method getColor() which returned the color of the ball object, calling the command

> > woo getColor
> >     Your color is red  (output that comes from Console.WriteLine("Your color is {0}", color))

This way the user could create batch files to run methods on a single object through multiple calls of the program.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want to write us the code? You won't get any answer then. This isn't a code service here :)

Comment: You don't really define what a session is. However, if it is to be persisted after the console app process has exited, would suggest that you write the last value to a config file.

Comment: You're going to have to serialize your data if you want to handle things that way. Either that, or have a service that runs in the background for woo.exe to talk to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way would be:

- call woo.exe, create object
- now woo.exe finishes, right? Serialize object to disk in any convenient format (I would choose XML as it is expressive and easy to parse in C#)
- woo.exe is called again with new parameters. Load object, make changes, serialize again.

Another possible way:

- woo.exe is loaded first time, creates object and waits.
- another instance is loaded, find first instance via inter-process communications (pipes or local network) and sends command (calls method) to it.
- first instance act like a server, holds the objects and executes changes to it.

Comment: After reading up more on the serialization method, I think I'm sold. I am using a program that behaves this way but couldn't find where they were storing the binary file. I need to write a similar program and will use the serialization method. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on @alxx's suggestions - it all depends on what that object does between property changes. If all it does is remember those values, use the first suggestion. If the object does something (if you set the color to red, something becomes red), then you probably need that something to live inside a process somewhere, that would be your own process, and you should go with the second suggestion.